# Windows 8.1 application does not do the NTLM Negotiation required by Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, wpf, windows-store-apps, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication

I have a Windows 8.1 Store application that I side-load on a Windows 10 Enterprise DELL tablet. The app uses data from a repository via an ASP.NET Web API installed on a remote server. The Web API is configured to use Windows Authentication. If I use Fiddler to make Web API calls I can see the several steps in the NTLM negotiation, the 401.2 HTTP Error messages returned twice before the HTTP 200 Ok.

However, my application gets the 401.1 and then it does not do anything else. In my application's package manifest, I have checked Enterprise Authentication check box in the list of required capabilities. Also, when I tested it with the Visual Studio Simulator, on my development machine, the negotiation was done and the Web API responded properly to my calls.

In order to have the NTLM Negotiation done automatically in the background, I though all that needs to be done is to have an HttpClientHandler object constructed like this:

```
var webApiAuthClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
   Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials,
   ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic
};
```

Then, this HttpClientHandler object would be passed in the constructor of the HttpClient object used to make the Web API calls:

```
var webApiHttpClient = new HttpClient(webApiAuthClientHandler)
{
   BaseAddress = new Uri(_myWebApiUri, UriKind.Absolute),
   Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 150)
};
```

What am I missing? How do I get my app to automatically negotiate the authentication in the background and have my GetAsync call return the needed HTTP Code 200?

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.
TIA,
Eddie

Answer (score 0):

I see your issue has been resolved in MSDN forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/58620579-240d-49da-8538-cee5aff91a68/w81-sideloaded-windows-81-application-generates-an-exception-when-calling-methods-of-an-restful?forum=wpdevelop
So I post it here to help more visitors find the solution easily.
Thank you.

Comment: Mattew, I had two separate questions on MSDN that were unfortunately merged. Only one was answered. The other one, also listed above, is still unanswered. So if anyone has an idea why the above described phenomen is happening, I would love to hear the solution.

Comment: Just so everyone understands, the first issue was the exception thrown by GetAsync. The inner message of this exception was "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 127.0.0.1:8888". I found out that this error message was due to the fact that Fiddler was also running on the tablet where I was trying to test my app. After Fiddler was stopped, I got the behaviour described in the body of this question.